# How to handle destroyItem if instantiateItem uses LinearLayout and RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

My problem is that when destroyItem is called, it currently destroys LinearLayouts, but my instantiateItem method instantiates both relative and linear layouts. So when destroyItem is called, it is getting an exception that relative layout can't be cast to linear layout. Ive tried if (object instanceof linearlayout) destroy that kind etc...

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    RelativeLayout wholeView = new RelativeLayout(collection.getContext());

    // images view
    RelativeLayout images = new RelativeLayout(collection.getContext());
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(collection.getContext());
        image.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        images.addView(image);
        image.setImageResource(GalImages[i]);
        if (i==1) {
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
        }
    }

    // text labels view
    LinearLayout textLabels = new LinearLayout(collection.getContext());
    textLabels.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView activityDescription = new TextView(collection.getContext());
    activityDescription.setText("Warm-up");
    activityDescription.setPadding(200, 200, 0, 0);
    activityDescription.setTextSize(30);
    textLabels.addView(activityDescription);

    TextView timeLeftForThisActivity = new TextView(collection.getContext());
    timeLeftForThisActivity.setText("00:00");
    timeLeftForThisActivity.setPadding(200, 0, 0, 0);
    timeLeftForThisActivity.setTextSize(60);
    textLabels.addView(timeLeftForThisActivity);

    TextView elapsedTimeStatic = new TextView(collection.getContext());
    elapsedTimeStatic.setText("Elapsed Time: ");
    elapsedTimeStatic.setPadding(200, 0, 0, 0);
    elapsedTimeStatic.setTextSize(20);
    textLabels.addView(elapsedTimeStatic);

    // adding images and text to overall view
    wholeView.addView(images);
    wholeView.addView(textLabels);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(wholeView, 0);

    return wholeView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the cast-  removeView doesn't need a LinearLayout, it just needs a View.  And both LinearLayout and RelativeLayout derive from View.